# Will I save energy by turning my heat completely off during the day?

Tags: heating

I have an 80's house with electric inertia radiators all over the place.

I have a connected thermostat (like [Heatzy](https://heatzy.com), but if you know better I'd love to hear about it). Is it worth turning everything off during the day, even if it means restarting 1 hour before my return?

I see everywhere that it's better to lower the heat instead of shutting all off when housing has average insulation... But I don't see the point, thermodynamically speaking. If I turn off the heat at 8am, there will be less heat loss during the day (lower temperature difference), even if I heat up at 5pm I should have consumed less?

Thank you for your help and pardon my English.

Comment: You seem to be asking, at least in part, why _others_ say what they do, but you haven't linked us to those others. Where exactly is "everywhere"?

Comment: _Others_ may be referring to the risk of water pipe freeze, but you're correct about absolute energy use--a lower temperature differential results in less heat exchange.

Comment: I don't know what an "inertia radiator" is.  did you mean electrical *resistance".  To comment on your question... I have a small mountain home that I leave it heat turned way down when we're not there, but while I can heat up the air with the forced air furnace relatively quickly, EVERY **THING** in the house is cold. Sit on the sofa and it's freezing, grab a cup for some tea and it's ice cold.   So it's a comfort thing. You might save some on heating costs, but sacrifice a level of comfort.  The other consideration is if you live in a freezing climate, you risk having freezing pipes.

Comment: Is `electric inertia radiator` an alternate term for `storage radiator`? Massive thing heated up overnight at off-peak rates, gives off heat through the day without further power input?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson you'd need really terrible insulation to worry about freezing pipes indoors when unheated for a few hours.  If that was the case the anything you could do to improve insulation would pay for itself very quickly

Comment: On the general thermodynamic question, I agree that for any system using direct heat from a fuel source, the bigger the setback the less heat you lose, and the more you save on energy costs. That works because the efficiency of direct heating doesn't change significantly when trying to cover a large temperature differential. However, if you have a heat pump smaller setbacks can be less expensive because heat pump efficiency drops significantly when a big temperature change is needed. Not the case here but just a comment on the general issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes:  Heat loss in your house is proportional to the difference between the outside temperature and the inside temperature.

Having the temperature drop during the day lowers the total lost heat, reducing energy usage *assuming that increasing the house temperature rapidly does not make the heating system less efficient*.

However, depending on the on vs off peak costs of energy, you may or may not save any money.

Comment: Re the last sentence: daytime is likely to be peak time so if you're charged different rates by time you'll probably save *more* than a crude estimate would suggest